# Is there any solutions for this set of equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Is there any solutions？ Why?How?
$$
\begin{array}{cccc}
3z &+ &4x + 3y &= 12\\
z &+ &4x + 3y &= 12\\
2z &+ &4x + 3y &= 12\\
\end{array}
$$

Comment: These are linear equations?

Comment: Well, by subtracting the second equation from the last, you can immediately see that $z=0$. What's the next step?

Comment: You don't show much effort on this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever the values of $x$ and $y$, $3z=z=2z$ must hold, and $$z=0.$$ Then the system reduces to

$$4x+3y=12.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let 
$$z+4x+3y=12$$
$$3z+4x+3y=12$$
$$2z+4x+3y=12$$
Multiplying the first equation by $$-3$$ and Adding to the second
$$-8x-6y=-24$$
and by the same way we get
$$-4x-3y=-12$$
Can you proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Assume there is a solution $x_0, y_0$, and $z_0  \not = 0$.

Then :

1) $az_0= 12-(4x_0+3y_0)$, where $a =1,2,3.$

Contradiction (Why?).

Hence $z_0=0.$

2) The 3 equations reduce to 1 equation:

$4x+3y=12.$

In 2D (recall $z_0=0$) this is a line.

Combining:

3)  Solutions:

$z_0=0$; and $4x+3y=12$ i.e.

$z_0=0$, and all points $x_0,y_0$ that satisfy $4x_0+3x_0= 12$.

Answer (score 0):

The solutions also depend on the "field". For a field of characteristic $p=2$ the system reduces to a single equation $z=y$. Otherwise, for $p\neq 2$, we obtain $2z=0$ and hence $z=0$, and the single equation $4x+3y=12$.

Answer (score -1):

Yes!! There are many solutions to this set of equations 
3z +4x +3y = 12z +4x +3y 
=> 3z = 12z 
=> z= 0 
Now, since 12 2z + 4x+3y =12 
=> 4x +3y =12  ( as z=0) 
=> 4*0 + 3*4 =12 ie x=0,y=4 ,z=0 
Or, 4*6/4 +3*2 =12 ie, x=3/2, y=2, z=0 
Or, 4*0 + 3*4 = 12 ie, x=0, y= 4, z= 0 
This way, x,y,z can hold infinite sets of values